# How do I configure nginx so that it sends response back to the server?

Tags: node.js, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I developed a **Node.js** web app that has both a client-side and a server-side.

The web app works perfectly locally, however now that I have deployed the **server.js** file to a remote server, the **server.js** successfully receives requests (**req**) from the client, **BUT** fails to send a response (**res**) back to the client. I assume this is an **nginx** configuration issue.

Kindly help me correctly configure my `nginx` file located in '/etc/nginx/conf.d/myserver.js' to ensure that my server sends responses to the client.

```
#The Nginx server instance
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/vincent_asea/quickd_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/sirbt/private.key;
    server_name quick.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location = /checkPaymentStatus {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/checkPaymentStatus$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```